# Counting without Stirling Method

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We have this question where:

"Let S be a set with |S| = 7. In how many ways can we partition the set
S into three nonempty parts?"

While our understanding of the question is not clear, we have used the "Stirling numbers of the second kind" formula to find an exact solution of 301. But we can't work around how we can find it. Is there any way to solve this without using Stirling Number Method and just elementary combination applied?

Answer (score 2):

For small cases like yours, you could simply  allot subsets to boxes in (say) descending order and divide by the number of boxes with equal number of elements.

$5-1-1:\; \binom75\binom21 \div 2= 21$

$4-2-1:\; \binom74\binom32 =105$

$3-3-1:\; \binom73\binom43 \div2 = 70$

$3-2-2:\; \binom73\binom32 \div2 =105$

Add up to get the correct answer of $\boxed{301}$

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks!